# Limit query results after receiving result

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm having sort of an issue with sorting and giving sort of a ranking while having pagination.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE approved=1 ORDER BY Likes DESC LIMIT $start_from, $num_rec_per_page"; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$i=1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo 'Rank: '.$i++.'. Name:'.$row[Name].'Likes: '.$row[Likes].'<br>';
}
```

This way, every page rank is given all over again.
My question is, how to Limit query only AFTER receiving all data, 
or maybe some advice on doing other way of pagionation.

**UPDATE:**
Fixed the problem by changing **$i=1;** to **$i=$start_from+1;**

Comment: It s not very clear to me , what exactly you are asking..

Answer (score 0):

Limiting the $i ?

```
$maxPerPage = 20;
$i = 0;
while($i < $maxPerPage && $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo 'Rank: '.$i++.'. Name:'.$row[Name].'Likes: '.$row[Likes].'<br>';
}
```

**But LIMITING in mysql (in your case) is better than getting all rows and fetching just some.**